# Set Application database dynamically in new computer

Tags: sql, entity-framework, window

I just finish building a window application.
In my program i use `entityframwork` and `sql 2008 express`.
The entityframework is binded to my local database.
my question is how can i make the connection dynamic,

meaning, how do i run my program in another computer, and automatically the program will use the machine database?

Answer (score 0):

Just put your database in `App_Data` folder and server as only `Data Source="."` in your connection string. BUt the other computer will still need `SQL Server Express` to be installed.

Comment: can i write a sql script to generate the entityframeowrk data base in the new computer?

Comment: @user1763180 hey, you seem to be a newbie in entity framework. You can use code first or model first and database will be autogenerated for you by the specified connection string at specified place. You can even seed data to the database.